# Alembic sequence only renders the first frame

Tags: rendering, animation, alembic

I'm trying to render out an alembic sequence. Rendering any single frame works fine, but rendering the entire frame range results in the first frame being repeated over and over.

This is what my output settings look like, I can't spot anything wrong with them:

[image]

I'm rendring it in Octane for blender, file attached.
Blender file and alembic sequence here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYKmAaiYbretHkr_BeVzBnqadwkA7SUt

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this is a known issue in the alembic importer for Blender. I hope they will fix this soon. source: https://developer.blender.org/T58704